# Stopover of 5 hours at tokyo NRT should I buy transit visa traveling from US to India

Tags: visas, airport-transfer, nrt

I am traveling on American Airline from Los Angles LAX to Bangalore,India on 23 dec 2013 there is layover and change of flight at Tokyo NRT and Malaysia. Layover time at NRT (4.20pm-9.40pm) is 5 hours should I but transit visa?

I have F1 visa and Citizen of India.

I searched there was an old answer (to buy transit visa only if layover of overnight we need to buy) any new updates?

Comment: Are you asking if you need to get a transit visa, or if you might want to?

Comment: Nothing has changed, hence closing as a duplicate.